# Java File create from path in another partition

Tags: java, windows

I am using Windows 10, latest JDK.

`System.out.println(new File("F:\\some\\path\\to\\file.wav").getAbsolutePath());`

This prints:

`F:\some\path\project_folder\F:\some\path\to\file.wav` !!!

Can you please explain what am I mistaking here? I tried even

`new File(URI.create("file:///F:/some/path/to/file.wav"))` but gives me

`/F:/some/path/to/file.wav` (a leading / makes it wrong)

Trying with only 2 slashes `file://F:/some/path/to/file.wav` I get an exception
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component`

**UPDATE**

This only occurs when I am referring to files in partition `F:\` (by the way, the project itself is in `F:\` also). Trying to refer to the `C:\` which is the system drive, works normally.

**UPDATE 2**
Turns out that there are some parent directories shared between the file and project (`F:\some\path\` in my example). Maybe this is the reason?!
I tried `new File("..\\to\\file.wav")` but also printing wrong `F:\some\path\project_folder\..\to\file.wav`

Comment: Do you have the permissions to create a file in `F:\\\`?

Comment: Yes, creating a file `F://some_file.wav` works

Comment: The problem could be related to [`File.isAbsolute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#isAbsolute()). The documentation says a file is absolute on Windows if it is prefixed with a drive specifier _followed by `"\\"`_. As `"F://"` works see if `"F:\\\\"` also works. (_Note: Using `"D:\\"` (non system drive) works for me._)

Comment: @Slaw Good point. The bad news is that it is also printing `F:\some\path\project_folder\F:\some\path\to\file.wav` even when putting `F:\\\\\`

Comment: What happens when you try NIO? `Paths.get("F:", "some", "path", "to", "file.wav").toAbsolutePath()`. And does `File.isAbsolute` return true for your original `File` object (before `getAbsolutePath()`)?

Comment: can you verify that `System.out.println("F:\\some\\path\\to\\file.wav".length());` returns 24? I suspect that there might be an invisible letter (like Unicode Left-To-Right-Mark) before or after the `F` and that because of this your path is not recognized as an absolute path

Answer (score -2):

you may copied path from windows file explorer
use / in your path string instead of \

Comment: Thank you. I tried that already. I have told in question I even tried URI with `file:///` prefix

Comment: try F:/some/path/to/file.wav i think it is correct path format